# How do I reset the Navigator.pop call back value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, callback, navigator

Please bear with my explanation below.
I have a page with 2 BottomNavigationBar Items:

```
Page1(),
Page2(),
```

In `Page1` there is a button which navigates to another page called `PostSomethingPage`:

```
// in Page1
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
   context, MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: 
     (context) => PostSomethingPage()))
        .then((isPostSuccess) => isPostSuccess 
          ? print('is Success!') : print('Failed!'));
```

You can see that `Page1` is expecting a return boolean value from `PostSomethingPage` and will print based on it.

Here is the code in `PostSomethingPage` that returns the result:

```
// in PostSomethingPage
Navigator.pop(context, isSuccess);
```

Then once we went back to `Page1`, the value from the call back has been received and the print statement was executed accordingly, everything seems fine at this point.

But then a problem arise when I navigate to `Page2` and back to `Page1` 
*Note: at this point I have been from `Page1` => `PostSomethingPage` => back to `Page1` with the result, after that then go to `Page2`*

Because when I went back again to `Page1` the print statement will get printed again based on the LAST known value. But what I want is to reset the call back value to be empty instead of having `true` or `false`

Comment: `callBackResult = null` before navigating to page2, or am i missing a point?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by `callBackResult` and how do I access that from `Page1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a variable to store the value return by PostSomethingPage

```
//our variable initialized with null
bool isPostSuccess;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FlatButton(onPressed: () async {
    //going to PostSomethingPage from Page1
    isPostSuccess = await Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: (context) {
          return PostSomethingPage();
        })
    );
  }, child: Text(''));
  //we are back at the Page1
  //isPostSuccess will not be null
}
```

now before you go to Page2 simply set the value of isPostSuccess to null again

```
    //going to Page2 from Page1
    isPostSuccess = null;
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: (context) {
          return Page2();
        })
    );
```